# Will collection with a huge array of document refs in mongodb cause performance slowdown?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongoose

I want to design a article schema that store a article and can record the user who starred it.

Here is the schema:

```
var AtricleSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'please enter the article name',
        trim: true,
        index: true
    },
    author: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },

    //Other field...

    starredByUser: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
});
```

I don't know whether it is a good practice to save the user who starred the article id in the article collection. What if there are so many people starred the article? e.g:200,000 user, and the article doc will be very large. will it make query or write the doc very slow?

such as these query:

`Article.find({starredByUser:ObjectId('my-user-id')})`

or

find the first five user who starred the article.

My design is no good on these condition, There must be a better solution, any kind of advice or example will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with many references / relations. Why do you want to use MongoDB? If you cannot "flatten" your problem to documents well, I don't think MongoDB is the ideal choice.

Furthermore, what are your access patterns, like reads vs writes, frequent queries,...? With NoSQL databases this makes a much bigger difference than with relational ones.